# On Android, How to prevent NFC intent-filtered app select popup on read NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

I'm making App which read NFC tag and and doing some task when NFC tagged.
When I tagged in my app, Select App popup opened. But I want to prevent opening this when NFC tag read in my app.
There was an app named "Tasker" which working exactly I want. How should I do?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />
```